# Connection url not visible while creating xa datasource mysql using Teiid

Tags: mysql, jdbc, datasource, xa, teiid

I am trying to create a mysql xa datasource, but am unable to mention connection url properties in it. I have used property names such as "URL" and "connection-url", but the property is not visible in datasource.

Also when I explicitly make a property tag in datasource for the url, it is working, but not when I am creating it through Admin Api,

I need the connection url to be set for the datasource, for using mysql connection arguments such as "rewriteBatchedStatements=true"

Answer (score 0):

I got to find a way to set connection url in xa-datasource. It is by setting a property called "connection-properties", and the value will be "URL=". It works for mysql and sqlserver xa datasources as far as I have checked.